# How to write HTML5 Data Attribute as JavaScript Array Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
 <span data-test="15, 17">
```

JavaScript / JQuery:

```
$value = [ $(object).data('test') ]
```

The $value variable now contains an array with one element. This element has the value "15, 17". I want to change the value of data-test in HTML in a way that $value will contain an array with two elements "15" and "17". In my environment I can only change the data-test attribute of the span. I can not change the JavaScript.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xfez/59/) how the result currently looks like: ["15, 17"]

But I need it to be: ["15", "17"]

Is there any way?

Edit 1: I want to highlight the following part again: **I can not change the JavaScript, only the HTML**

Edit 2: I guess from the answers and comments below that with these requirements it is not possible to achieve the result I aimed for.

Comment: You can do it with javascript _split()_ method: _https://jsfiddle.net/3xfez/60/_

Comment: If you really "**can not change the JavaScript**", then, no. You can't quite get the result you want. Rory's answer will get you an array-within-an-array, but that's as close as you'll get.

Comment: if  you cant change the javascript, is impossible what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer: is impossible what you want, if you can't change the Javascript.

However, using javascript, an way to do is:

```
var array = $('#demo').data('test').split(',');
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/3xfez/65/ (Don't forget to open the console.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the value as a serialised array, in other words like this:

```
<span data-test="[15, 17]">
```

When jQuery stores it in the data cache object it will be deserialised to an array:

```
var value = $('span').data('test'); // == Array
console.log(value.length); // = 2
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3xfez/61/)

Comment: Note that, for some reason, OP can change the HTML, but *not* the Javascript - so `$value = [ $(object).data('test') ]` will be run, giving `[ [15, 17 ] ]`

Comment: @PaulRoub good point. I would highly suggest changing the JS if possible though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the array in JSON format.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3xfez/62/

The correct data value should be: [15, 17].

```
<span id="demo" data-test="[15, 17]"></div>
```

Comment: You're linking to the OP's original fiddle, nothing changed there. And your code here has the same issue that's leading the OP to go all boldfaced - the JS can't be changed. You'll get nested arrays.

Comment: Nested array is not possible

Comment: @PaulRoub changed the fiddle. You're right that it will be a nested array, but it is still the only way to get an array from the data attribute from the provided js.